# Intel SpeedStep / Turbo on Supermicro server not working

Tags: supermicro

I recently acquired a used Supermicro SuperServer 6027AX-TRF-HFT3 (with 2x E5-2687W v2).
It has been working pretty well so far, however I noticed one thing.
No matter what I do, it does not seem to be able to downclock in idle or turbo up under use.
I have enabled EIST and Turbo in the BIOS, and disabled the option of overriding OS power management. I have also enabled all C and P states I could find options for.
HyperSpeed is set to all "Auto", which was the only option for it to not overclock the CPU.

The output of cpupower is as follows

```
# cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 4.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 4.00 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 3.40 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    3700 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    3800 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    3900 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    4000 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

Trying to disable the pstate driver and using the ACPI legacy just yields in `hardware limit: 3.40 GHz - 3.40 GHz` so then it doesn't even show what clocks it can do anymore.

First attempt energy saving settings
[image: First attempt energy saving settings]

Second attempt energy saving settings
[image: Second attempt energy saving settings]

Chipset settings
[image: Chipset settings]

Overclock / HyperSpeed settings
[image: Overclock / HyperSpeed settings]